# Logic Apps / MS Graph API: Quarantine an email autonomously

Tags: email, microsoft-graph-api, azure-logic-apps, azure-sentinel

I want to be able to quarantine an email after some custom logic. Such as an alert in Azure Sentinel or KQL.

A sample solution I thought was:
[image]
Once an incident occurs the email entity is taken and then the email is quarantined. (We'll obtain the networkmessageid from emailevent logs)

However, I'm struggling to figure out what logic app module to use to quarantine?

- Is it possible to do via graph API and what permission does the app
  registration need to perform that action?
- Is there any existing module on logic apps - maybe exchange or outlook module?

Comment: Have you tried using **Microsoft Sentinel alert** as given https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sentinel/playbook-triggers-actions#update-an-incident

Comment: yes, im already doing that... the question is how to quarantine an email using logic apps or graph api or another azure service autonomously. in my example i used a sentinel alert as a trigger.

Answer (score 1):

You could submit the email as a threat, if it contains malicious content. That's better than moving it to quarantine, because this way it could that Microsoft updates it's filters or machine learning algorithms

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/security-emailthreatsubmission?view=graph-rest-beta

Comment: the workflow is: Sentinel analytic rule -> logic app/playbook sentinel trigger on rule -> quarantine -> human intervention to verify due to the complexities of the original analytic rule.  I want to be able to track this very specific attack vector, hence I want to be able to quarantine and look at it

Comment: I haven't found a way to quarantine the message using the graph api, but if you want to look at it you can use the get message https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-get?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: There's a graph api mentioned in this forum post, but i cant find the query: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1365900/what-microsoft-api-can-be-used-to-move-an-endusers

Comment: I only found powershell to view the quarantined messages. It looks like in eop you can't quarantine yourself https://github.com/12Knocksinna/Office365itpros/blob/master/ReportQuarantinedMessages.PS1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I want to achieve:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1365900/what-microsoft-api-can-be-used-to-move-an-endusers

Looking for the graph query needed to go from networkmessageid from the sentinel alert to quarantining that email .